# Check for valid ADO.NET / OLEDB connection

Tags: c#, ado.net, ssis, oledb, custom-component

With a lot of help from everyone, I managed the following piece of code which works fine for only ADO.NET connection. But when I change my connection to OLEDB, this seems to fail. I am not sure why its happening, but would like to resolve this with your help.

The intention of this code is to check for either ADO.NET or OLEDB connection presence. If neither of them is not present, it raises an error. If either of them is present, then use that connection type to insert the variables values to the table.

Any suggestions, improvements are welcome!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace AOC.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks

{

[DtsTask(
    DisplayName = "Custom Logging Task",
    Description = "Writes logging info into a table")]
public class CustomLoggingTask : Task
{

    private string _packageName;
    private string _taskName;
    private string _errorCode;
    private string _errorDescription;
    private string _machineName;
    private double _packageDuration;

    private string _connectionName;
    private string _eventType;
    private string _executionid;
    private DateTime _handlerdatetime;
    public string ConnectionName
    {
        set
        {
            _connectionName = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return _connectionName;
        }
    }


    public string Event
    {
        set
        {
            _eventType = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return _eventType;
        }
    }


    public override DTSExecResult Validate(Connections connections, VariableDispenser variableDispenser, IDTSComponentEvents componentEvents, IDTSLogging log)
    {
        const string METHOD_NAME = "CustomLoggingTask-Validate";

        try
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_eventType))
            {
                componentEvents.FireError(0, METHOD_NAME, "The event property must be specified", "", -1);
                return DTSExecResult.Failure;
            }


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_connectionName))
            {
                componentEvents.FireError(0, METHOD_NAME, "No connection has been specified", "", -1);
                return DTSExecResult.Failure;
            }

            DbConnection connection = connections[_connectionName].AcquireConnection(null) as DbConnection;
            if (connection == null)
            {
                componentEvents.FireError(0, METHOD_NAME, "The connection is not a valid ADO.NET connection", "", -1);
                return DTSExecResult.Failure;
            }

            if (!variableDispenser.Contains("System::SourceID"))
            {
                componentEvents.FireError(0, METHOD_NAME, "No System::SourceID variable available. This task can only be used in an Event Handler", "", -1);
                return DTSExecResult.Failure;
            }

            return DTSExecResult.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            componentEvents.FireError(0, METHOD_NAME, "Validation Failed: " + exc.ToString(), "", -1);
            return DTSExecResult.Failure;
        }
    }


    public override DTSExecResult Execute(Connections connections, VariableDispenser variableDispenser, IDTSComponentEvents componentEvents, IDTSLogging log, object transaction)
    {
        try
        {
            string commandText =
@"INSERT INTO SSISLog (EventType, PackageName, TaskName, EventCode, EventDescription, PackageDuration, Host, ExecutionID, EventHandlerDateTime)
VALUES (@EventType, @PackageName, @TaskName, @EventCode, @EventDescription, @PackageDuration, @Host, @Executionid, @handlerdatetime)";

            ReadVariables(variableDispenser);
            DbConnection connection = connections[_connectionName].AcquireConnection(transaction) as DbConnection;
            //SqlConnection connection = (SqlConnection)connections[_connectionName].AcquireConnection(transaction);
            DbCommand command = null;
            //using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            if (connection is SqlConnection)
                command = new SqlCommand();
            else if (connection is OleDbConnection)
                command = new OleDbCommand();

            {
                command.CommandText = commandText;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.Connection = connection;

                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EventType", _eventType));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PackageName", _packageName));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TaskName", _taskName));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EventCode", _errorCode ?? string.Empty));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EventDescription", _errorDescription ?? string.Empty));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PackageDuration", _packageDuration));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Host", _machineName));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ExecutionID", _executionid));
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@handlerdatetime", _handlerdatetime));
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            return DTSExecResult.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            componentEvents.FireError(0, "CustomLoggingTask-Execute", "Task Errored: " + exc.ToString(), "", -1);
            return DTSExecResult.Failure;
        }
    }


    private void ReadVariables(VariableDispenser variableDispenser)
    {
        variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::StartTime");
        variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::PackageName");
        variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::SourceName");
        variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::MachineName");
        variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::ExecutionInstanceGUID");
        variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::EventHandlerStartTime");
        bool includesError = variableDispenser.Contains("System::ErrorCode");
        if (includesError)
        {
            variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::ErrorCode");
            variableDispenser.LockForRead("System::ErrorDescription");
        }

        Variables vars = null;
        variableDispenser.GetVariables(ref vars);

        DateTime startTime = (DateTime)vars["System::StartTime"].Value;
        _packageDuration = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalSeconds;
        _packageName = vars["System::PackageName"].Value.ToString();
        _taskName = vars["System::SourceName"].Value.ToString();
        _machineName = vars["System::MachineName"].Value.ToString();
        _executionid = vars["System::ExecutionInstanceGUID"].Value.ToString();
        _handlerdatetime = (DateTime)vars["System::EventHandlerStartTime"].Value;
        if (includesError)
        {
            _errorCode = vars["System::ErrorCode"].Value.ToString();
            _errorDescription = vars["System::ErrorDescription"].Value.ToString();
        }

        // release the variable locks.
        vars.Unlock();

        // reset the dispenser
        variableDispenser.Reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: is it throwing an error or just running through and not returning the expected result?

Comment: When I use the DLL generated by this code in SSIS, it just works for ADO.NET connection type. If I use an OLEDB type connection, it fails on me saying that "[CustomLoggingTask-Validate] Error: The connection is not a valid ADO.NET connection". I put the check in there to make sure that it handles both ADO.NET and OLEDB, but dont know why its giving me this error.

Comment: My guess is that OLEDB doesn't understand what DbConnection is even though it inherits from DbConnection.

Comment: Any work around to make this thing work? Essentially, this dll should be able to handle both the types of connection.